# Getting the names of users on apt-get logs

Tags: apt, log

I am administering a Ubuntu server (Trusty) where several users have been given permission to run apt-get, but only two administrators have full sudo permission.

I want to keep track of who installs what on the server. The /var/log/apt/history.log maintains a log of what apt-get commands were run. However, this does not keep track of the user who ran the command. Is there a work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For apt-get the one installing applications was the user `root` since he's the only one that can write on the entire filesystem. You must check instead the `auth.log` file for the specific users that ran apt-get using `sudo`. If they use `sudo` to login as root, then there's nothing much you can do.